# Bootstrap 4.3.1 carousel does not working for Angular 8

Tags: windows-10

My ngb-carousel worked perfectly using Angular 7 and Bootstrap 4.1.1.  However after I upgrade Angular to version 8 and Bootstrap to version 4.3.1, the carousel does not display correctly any more. I put simplest codes as follow:

```
<ngb-carousel >
    <ng-template ngbSlide>
        <div>First</div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbSlide>
        <div>Second</div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbSlide>
        <div>Third</div>
    </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

All carousel items are displayed at once in order, as:

```
 1.
 2.
 3.

First
Second
Third
PreviousNext
```

I have no idea what I missed, seems like the bootstrap style is not recognized.  However, I did modified angular.json to include bootstrap style:

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "src/styles.css"
],
```